# Multi File Uploading using jQuery and PHP. Creating the most simplified Example

Tags: php, jquery, html, file-upload

I would like to create a multifile file uploader using jQuery.

Below is the code I am working with. I am just trying to abstract out the essentials to uploading multiple files at once using jQuery (and File API) and PHP. If anyone has a simplified answer feel free to share or offer suggestions.

Right now this code works to upload the images(kinda), however. There are issues:

1. Even after selecting more than one file, only one file uploads to the directory
2. The form changes the page upon submit

Here is the js/jquery I am working with:

```
function html5Upload($form) {
    file = $form.data('input');
    if (file) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append($form.find(selector).attr('name'), file);
        //get other form input and append to formData
        $form.find(':input').each(function () {
            if (this.type != 'file') {
                fd.append($(this).attr('name'), $(this).val());
            }
        });

        //Upload using jQuery AJAX
        jqxhr = $.ajax({
            url: $form.attr('action'),
            data: fd,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function () {
                alert("Images Uploaded!");
            }
        });
    }

    $form.remove();
}


$('form').submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    html5Upload($('form.mupload'));
    return false;
});
```

**HTML**

```
<form class="mupload" action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="userfile" class="fileUpload" multiple>

    <button type="submit">Upload</button>
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
/*
Easy PHP Upload - version 2.32
A easy to use class for your (multiple) file uploads

Copyright (c) 2004 - 2010, Olaf Lederer
*/
include("easy_upload/upload_class.php");

$upload = new file_upload();

$upload->upload_dir = 'uploads/';
$upload->extensions = array('.png', '.jpg', '.zip', '.pdf'); // specify the allowed extensions here
$upload->rename_file = true;


if(!empty($_FILES)) {
    $upload->the_temp_file = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];
    $upload->the_file = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
    $upload->http_error = $_FILES['userfile']['error'];
    $upload->do_filename_check = 'y'; // use this boolean to check for a valid filename
    if ($upload->upload()){

        echo '<div id="status">success</div>';
        echo '<div id="message">'. $upload->file_copy .' Successfully Uploaded</div>';
        //return the upload file
        echo '<div id="uploadedfile">'. $upload->file_copy .'</div>';

    } else {

        echo '<div id="status">failed</div>';
        echo '<div id="message">'. $upload->show_error_string() .'</div>';

    }
}
```

Comment: What does the title have to do with your question?

Comment: oops. My bad I forgot to change it. StackOverflow saved my last question in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen a few potential problem so far:

1. Only one file uploaded.

   - For multiple file upload, I think the `name` attributes of the file input should be something like `userfiles[]`. This way it will not be overwritten. FYI: if two HTML input have the same name without `[]`, only the latter will be send over the request. `[]` can also be used to send any data that have multiple values such as `select` (think of Array, and it is represented as array in $_POST).
   - I don't really know your upload handler, are you sure it can handle multiple file upload?
2. I guess you included the script tag before the `form`? Try put the event code inside jQuery domReady like so

.

```
$(function() {
     $('form').submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        html5Upload($('form.mupload'));
        return false;
    });
});
```

You might want to check this issue first.